# Regular Expressions sql oracle to ensure that order number entered into the database in a standard format

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to select a String field (contains a text like LOREM) that has an order number with a specific quantity of characters (1- and 11 digits), however, don't know do it.

How do I write an SQL query that returns me only the 13 digits of number (4-70000000000) order?

```
select 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima porro, hic deleniti pariatur quaerat eligendi mollitia 4-70000000000 (praesentium)'
    from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regexp_substr()`.  Your number is not exactly a number, but this works for the example in your question:

```
select regexp_substr('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima porro, hic deleniti pariatur quaerat eligendi mollitia 4-70000000000 (praesentium)',
                 '[-0-9]{13}')
from dual;
```

Comment: Thanks, Gordon Linoff!! By the way, it worked like I was thinking.